# Wso2 gadget server portal customization

Tags: wso2

I have been looking quite extensively into the WSO2 Application and Gadget servers. In all the reading through the Gadget server info and watching presentations I have discovered that the portal side of the GS can be themed, which is great, but I have been looking to customize the actual design of the portal, which is proving more difficult.

Being able to add a layout for tabs on the portal would be great, as well as being able to add or change the whole header of the portal (beyond theme changes possible with CSS).

Anyone got any pointers on if either of those that is possible?

Answer (score 1):

I have also been looking into this and i found the following article [1] by Lahiru Gunathilake at WSO2 to be very useful. Hope this helps

[1] http://wso2.org/library/knowledge-base/2010/11/customize-ui-theming-wso2-carbon-based-products

Answer (score 1):

Above mentioned link[1] will help on changing theming of management console view of each WSO2 product.

If you are looking for customize the portal view of WSO2 Gadget Server 1.x,it's correct that with GS 1.x releases, though you can change the portal theme as in [2],it's difficult to do much more UI customizations such as add a layout to tabs,etc.

But with coming releases of the new WSO2 product called User Engagement Server [Renamed WSO2 Gadget Server product with a new rich features set and which has already released its first milestone],you can achieve your requirement very easily.

Thanks;

[1]  http://wso2.org/library/knowledge-base/2010/11/customize-ui-theming-wso2-carbon-based-products

[2] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/GS140/Changing+Portal+Theme

Comment: the probable release date of intial version - User Engagement Server ?